# MRTK "Console" appears in one eye when build

Tags: unity-game-engine, runtime-error, windows-mixed-reality

I have a problem, When I have built the solution, a runtime error appears in one eye on a corner. Is imposible to read, but I got a log file that sais what its on the console (I can read only the corner and I think is the same) and we are tested in debug, release, master... and the error persist. In editor mode on Unity, the error dont appear. The experience is the same but I cant have this.

I dont find anything on their documentation, and this happens in 2019 (where im working right now) and 2018.
Im using MRTK 2.0 RC1 Refresh.
Im working with Lenovo Explorer with Motion Controllers.

````
Loading native plugins
  Loading AudioPluginMsHRTF.dll
Module information:
 Built with Compiler Ver '191627012'
 Built from '2019.1/staging' branch
 Version is '2019.1.0f2 (292b93d75a2c)'
 Release build
 Application type 'D3D'
 OS 'Windows 10 (10.0.17763) 64bit'
PlayerConnection initialized from E:/UNITY_2019_PROJECTS/BUILD VISUAL STUDIO/build/bin/x64/Release/AppX/Data (debug = 0)
PlayerConnection initialized network socket : 0.0.0.0 55050
Multi-casting "[IP] 172.30.13.181 [Port] 55050 [Flags] 2 [Guid] 737340049 [EditorId] 0 [Version] 1048832 [Id] UWPPlayerX64(MyPC) [Debug] 0 [PackageName] MyProject_vvjrt7vn67k36" to [225.0.0.222:54997]...
Started listening to [0.0.0.0:55050]
PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [0.0.0.0:55050]
Plugins: Failed to load 'WindowsMRXRSDK' because one or more of its dependencies could not be loaded.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Misc/Plugins.cpp Line: 223)

GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.1]
    Renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti (ID=0x1c82)
    Vendor:   
    VRAM:     4018 MB
Initialize engine version: 2019.1.0f2 (292b93d75a2c)
Failed to find spatial stage root, falling back to stationary tracking space type!

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/HoloLens/HoloLensWorldManager.cpp Line: 591)

Created eye textures with a "texture array" layout.  The "single-pass instancing" stereo mode will be used.

Windows Mixed Reality spatial locatability state changed to Activating.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/HoloLens/HoloLensWorldManager.cpp Line: 374)

The referenced script (Unknown) on this Behaviour is missing!

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Scripting/ManagedReference/SerializableManagedRef.cpp Line: 197)

The referenced script on this Behaviour (Game Object '<null>') is missing!

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Mono/ManagedMonoBehaviourRef.cpp Line: 333)

A scripted object (probably Microsoft.MixedReality.Toolkit.Input.MixedRealityInputSimulationProfile?) has a different serialization layout when loading. (Read 76 bytes but expected 288 bytes)
Did you #ifdef UNITY_EDITOR a section of your serialized properties in any of your scripts?

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Serialize/SerializedFile.cpp Line: 2012)

UnloadTime: 41,373700 ms
Windows Mixed Reality spatial locatability state changed to Inhibited.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/HoloLens/HoloLensWorldManager.cpp Line: 374)

Setting up 3 worker threads for Enlighten.
  Thread -> id: 36ac -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: 4944 -> priority: 1 
  Thread -> id: 5280 -> priority: 1 
Windows Mixed Reality spatial locatability state changed to Active.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/HoloLens/HoloLensWorldManager.cpp Line: 374)

Windows Mixed Reality spatial locatability state changed to Inhibited.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/HoloLens/HoloLensWorldManager.cpp Line: 374)

Windows Mixed Reality spatial locatability state changed to Active.

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Modules/VR/HoloLens/HoloLensWorldManager.cpp Line: 374)

Trimming D3D resources.```
````

Comment: So what are you asking? Do you want to fix the errors or get rid of the message in your one eye?

Comment: I would like to get rid. I dont know what causes that it appears because its only when i build it into visual studio

Answer (score -1):

I look very thoroughly and found this in the Player settings in Project Settings.

Turning them all to none might help.

[image]